# How to replace NSMutableArray List data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am very new for IOS. In my app, I have inserted two `UIButtons` on my `mainViewController`

When I click first button I am adding some data in my Main `NSMutableArray` and when I click "second" button I want remove previous array details and replace new data.

### My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender{

    NSMutableArray * data1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
    initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

    [mainArray replacementObject:data1];
}

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender{
    NSMutableArray * data2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                              initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

     [mainArray removeObjectAtIndex:data2];
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender{

    NSMutableArray * data1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
    initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

    [mainArray addObject:data1];
}

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender{
    NSMutableArray * data2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                              initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

     [mainArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:data2];
}
```

I assumed your mainArray contains only one element. If there are more elements you need to specify correct index

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender{
    [mainArray addObjectsFromArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc]
                                    initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil]];
}

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender{
    [mainArray replaceObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, mainArray.count) withObjectsFromArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc]
                                                                            initWithObjects:@"6",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    - (IBAction)button1:(id)sender{

        mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                                  initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    }

    - (IBAction)button2:(id)sender{
        mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                                  initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
    }
```